# Reference to class method php

Tags: php, oop

I'd like to create a variable that 'points' to a class method like this:

```
$obj = $this->myMethod();
$obj->call();
```

or

```
$obj = $myClass->myMethod();
$obj->call();
```

Is this possible?

Edit:

Why I'd like to be able to do this:

```
private $default_field_callback = array(
        "methods" => array(
            "timestamp" => array(
                "object" => {object},
                "method" => "getTimestamp",
                "params" => array("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: `$obj = $this->myMethod()` will result in `$obj` containing whatever `$this->myMethod();` *returns*, not an "instance" of `$this->myMethod()`.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I realize that, but I don't want to call $this->myMethod(), I just want a callable object.

Comment: What's the point of doing this? Can you give us more detail please?

Comment: I'd like to have an array of callback methods for validating a form.

Answer (score 3):

you can make use of `call_user_func()` with this array structure indicating a class/method call.

```
$result = call_user_func(array($this,'myMethod'));
```

http://www.php.net/function.call-user-func read up for more information and parameter usage

Edit: see also `call_user_func_array()` to feed in your parameters as a single array

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php